# How to get the td having rowspan and split it to the next tr element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code

```
 $('table td').each(function() {
        var td = $(this).attr('rowspan');
        if (td > 0) {
        var tdVal = $(this).html();
        for (var j = 0; j < td; j++) {
            var newRow = $(this).clone();
            newRow.removeAttr('rowspan');
            newRow.html(tdVal);
            $(this).after(newRow);
        }
    $(this).remove();
   count++;
 } else {

}
});
```

Here is my html

```
<tr style="height:15.0pt;"><input value="" class="dt-checkboxes" id="row_0" type="checkbox">
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1" rowspan="2">Total general</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><input value="" class="dt-checkboxes" id="row_1" type="checkbox">
            <td class="td_0_1">Modalidad</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Ramo</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LBC-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">CRI-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">ILL-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">ALI-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">BIS-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">FOR-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">LAT-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">TOT. SG</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">BUP-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LVI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LBC-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">PRO-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">NAL-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">ALI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">CRDI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">TOT. SP</td>
          </tr>
```

From the above code, I have a td containing rowspan.
What i need is to add the rowspan td to next tr such as after

```
<td class="td_0_1">TOT. SP</td>
```

and empty the rowspan value and the respective td value using jquery.

**NOTE:** After the process, rowspan attribute should be removed .

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that it's always the last `td` in your first `tr` that has the `rowspan` and that there's no other `rowspan`s or `colspan`s happening in the table. If that's not the case then the code below will not work and things will get much more complex.

I've made an example below that checks the last `td` in the first `tr` for a `rowspan`. If found and spanning more than 1 row it will then go through all of the `tr`s that come after the first `tr` and append a clone of the last `td`. This will be done for the number of rows as indicated in the `rowspan`, so in my example the last row is not affected since it's not part of the `rowspan`.

I haven't used your html for my example since I think the effect is better illustrated in a more simple example. I've also added a button to perform the action so you can better see what happens. In your own code you should obviously ommit this button and the click event that goes with it.

***EDIT**

I just noticed that you wanted the content of the other last `td`s to be cleared as well, so I added it in the example.*

```js
function removeRowspan() {
  var $firstTr = $('table tr:first');
  var $lastTd = $firstTr.children('td:last');
  var rowspan = $lastTd.attr('rowspan');
  $lastTd.removeAttr('rowspan');
  if (rowspan && rowspan>1) {
    $firstTr.nextAll('tr').each(function(i) {
      if (i==rowspan-2) {
        $(this).append($lastTd.clone());
        return false;
      }
      else {
        $(this).append($('<td>'));
      }
    });
    $lastTd.html('');
  }
}

$('#remove-rowspan').on('click',removeRowspan);
```

```css
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
    <td>1.4</td>
    <td>1.5</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
    <td>2.4</td>
    <td>2.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
    <td>3.4</td>
    <td>3.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4.1</td>
    <td>4.2</td>
    <td>4.3</td>
    <td>4.4</td>
    <td>4.5</td>
    <td>4.6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="remove-rowspan">Remove rowspan</button>
```

Using your own html that would become:

```js
$(function() {
  var $firstTr = $('table tr:first');
  var $lastTd = $firstTr.children('td:last');
  var rowspan = $lastTd.attr('rowspan');
  $lastTd.removeAttr('rowspan');
  if (rowspan && rowspan>1) {
    $firstTr.nextAll('tr').each(function(i) {
      if (i==rowspan-2) {
        $(this).append($lastTd.clone());
        return false;
      }
      else {
        $(this).append($('<td>'));
      }
    });
    $lastTd.html('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr style="height:15.0pt;"><input value="" class="dt-checkboxes" id="row_0" type="checkbox">
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1" rowspan="2">Total general</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><input value="" class="dt-checkboxes" id="row_1" type="checkbox">
            <td class="td_0_1">Modalidad</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Ramo</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LBC-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">CRI-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">ILL-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">ALI-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">BIS-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">FOR-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">LAT-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">TOT. SG</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">BUP-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LVI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LBC-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">PRO-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">NAL-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">ALI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">CRDI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">TOT. SP</td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So this will be dynamic ?

Comment: @eThan_hunT Yes it should work for any amount of rows and any rowspan value. I added a snippet using your own html at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah got it thank you so much @vi5ion, If you found question useful upvote this.!

Comment: Hi, Now I have got trouble in this, There may be any number of rowspan, So i need to be fixed in Dynamic way not only the last TD.. Can you help me out to get this @vi5ion

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get parent element (which is `tr`) and [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get next element (next `tr`) and [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append cloned `td` at the end of the `tr` children.

Use this:

```
$(this).parent().next().append(newRow);
```

instead of

```
$(this).after(newRow);
```

```js
 $('table td').each(function() {
        var td = $(this).attr('rowspan');
        if (td > 0) {
        var tdVal = $(this).html();
        for (var j = 0; j < td; j++) {
            var newRow = $(this).clone();
            newRow.removeAttr('rowspan');
            newRow.html(tdVal);
            $(this).parent().next().append(newRow);
        }
    $(this).removeAttr('rowspan');
    $(this).empty();
 } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr style="height:15.0pt;"><input value="" class="dt-checkboxes" id="row_0" type="checkbox">
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Seguros de Personas</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="td_0_1" rowspan="2">Total general</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><input value="" class="dt-checkboxes" id="row_1" type="checkbox">
            <td class="td_0_1">Modalidad</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">Ramo</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LBC-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">CRI-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">ILL-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">ALI-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">BIS-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">FOR-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">LAT-G</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">TOT. SG</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">BUP-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LVI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">LBC-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">PRO-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">NAL-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">ALI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_3">CRDI-P</td>
            <td class="td_0_1">TOT. SP</td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Even though this might solve the op's question a little explanation would be appreciated. Also you can use the SO snippet not a jsfiddle link which ( in most cases ) becomes obsolete after a period of time

Comment: This actually adds the clone twice to each row (or even more if the rowspan would be greater than 2). Also, instead of clearing the initial `td` it is removed instead. These two things both create a broken table since the number of `td`s in every row are not the same.

Comment: As mentioned in code snippet shared in question, rowspan value is used to loop and add td to next element (based on rowspan value).

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code, It worked as my expectation, but i need to empty the paren td value. How is it possible

Comment: Updated code snippet. Hope you need to remove `rowspan` attribute and empty td content.

Comment: Hi, I need to append only once, because if rowspan="3" means only the 3rd td should have the clone value and rest should have empty values. It comes in dynamic way, How to handle this

Comment: Hi @Unknown, Are you able to give solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918995/how-to-get-the-td-having-the-rowspan-with-value-and-split-into-individual-td-usi